# CakePHP 3 is using primary key (setPrimaryKey) to do a JOIN even though I've specified a foreign key

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.x

CakePHP 3.7

I have 2 model Table classes as follows:

1. `/src/Model/Table/SubstancesTable.php`
2. `/src/Model/Table/TblOrganisationSubstancesTable.php`

The schema for each table in MySQL is as follows:

1.

```
mysql> describe substances;
+-------------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type                  | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | mediumint(8) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| app_id      | varchar(8)            | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
| name        | varchar(1500)         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| date        | date                  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

2.

```
mysql> describe tbl_organisation_substances;
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| o_sub_id    | int(255)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| o_id        | int(255)     | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| app_id      | varchar(15)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| os_name     | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| ec          | varchar(35)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| cas         | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| upload_id   | int(100)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I've written a custom finder which needs to perform a `JOIN` between these 2 tables. The custom finder looks like this and is in `SubstancesTable.php`:

```
public function findDistinctSubstancesByOrganisation(Query $query, array $options)
{
    $o_id = $options['o_id'];

    $query = $this->find()->select('id')->contain('TblOrganisationSubstances')->where(['TblOrganisationSubstances.o_id' => $o_id]);

    return $query;
}
```

Each table has an `app_id` column and this is the foreign key that links the 2 tables.

Initially I was getting an error:

> The TblOrganisationSubstances association is not defined on Substances.

Which made sense as no definitions had been put in place.

So in `SubstancesTable.php` I've defined this:

```
$this->setPrimaryKey('id');

// ...

$this->belongsTo('TblOrganisationSubstances', [
    'foreignKey' => 'app_id',
    'joinType' => 'INNER'
]);
```

But this produces the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT Substances.id AS `Substances__id` FROM substances Substances INNER JOIN tbl_organisation_substances TblOrganisationSubstances ON TblOrganisationSubstances.o_sub_id = (Substances.app_id) WHERE TblOrganisationSubstances.o_id = :c0
```

This isn't going to work because `TblOrganisationSubstances.o_sub_id = (Substances.app_id)` is wrong. It needs to JOIN based on `app_id`, in other words it should be:

```
TblOrganisationSubstances.app_id = (Substances.app_id)
```

I also tried changing the `belongsTo` to a `hasMany` association (not even sure which one is right here!):

```
$this->hasMany('TblOrganisationSubstances', [
    'foreignKey' => 'app_id',
]);
```

But the joining doesn't even seem to occur. The SQL produced is:

```
SELECT Substances.id AS `Substances__id` FROM substances Substances WHERE TblOrganisationSubstances.o_id = :c0
```

I also tried putting a `belongsTo` in `TblOrganisationSubstances.php` to try and define the relationship from both sides:

```
$this->belongsTo('Substances', [
    'foreignKey' => 'app_id',
    'joinType' => 'INNER'
]);
```

Again, this doesn't work. It produces the SQL without the join.

Please can someone help in terms of advising which is the correct type of association (`hasMany` vs `belongsTo`) and how to perform the join based on `app_id`, which is the foreign key that links the 2 tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a `BelongsTo` association, the *source* table holds the foreign key, hence with your configuration it will use `app_id` on `Substances`, and compare against the primary key of `TblOrganisationSubstances`.

In order to get the query that you're looking for, you also have to define the `bindingKey`, ie the foreign key of the *target* table, so that it doesn't use its primary key:

```php
$this->belongsTo('TblOrganisationSubstances', [
    'foreignKey' => 'app_id', // Substances.app_id
    'bindingKey' => 'app_id', // TblOrganisationSubstances.app_id
    'joinType' => 'INNER'
]);
```

Whether it's `HasMany` or `BelongsTo` is dictated by your data, and what and how you want to retrieve it. Generally if one `Substances` has 0 or 1 `TblOrganisationSubstances` (`1:1`), then it's `BelongsTo` or `HasOne`. If one `Substances` can have more than 1 `TblOrganisationSubstances` (`1:n`), then it's `HasMany`.

And if you want to filter by a `HasMany` association, then you need to use either matching or a join (`matching()`, `innerJoinWith()`, `leftJoinWith()`), as `HasMany` associated records will be retrieved in a separate query when using `contain()`.

See also

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Associations - Linking Tables Together](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html)**
- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Query Builder > Filtering by Associated Data](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#filtering-by-associated-data)**

Comment: This is right and +1 for mentioning matching as I will want to be doing this later on as well.

Answer (score -1):

SELECT * FROM `sample` LEFT JOIN `user` ON `sample`.`rac_id`=`user`.`userrac_id` UNION ALL SELECT * FROM `sample` RIGHT JOIN user ON `sample`.`rac_id`=`user`.`userrac_id`

Comment: its demo example for clear the concept of inner join with the help of this create your own code. there are two table sample and user and i try to apply innerjoin in sql query

Comment: This has literally nothing to do with the question asked and doesn't use any of the equivalent tables given in the question.

Answer (score -1):

`````
    public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
        'Ingredient' =>
            array(
                'className' => 'Ingredient',
                'joinTable' => 'ingredients_recipes',
                'foreignKey' => 'recipe_id',
                'associationForeignKey' => 'ingredient_id',
                'unique' => true,
                'conditions' => '',
                'fields' => '',
                'order' => '',
                'limit' => '',
                'offset' => '',
                'finderQuery' => '',
                'with' => ''
            )
    );
}````
`````

Comment: This has literally nothing to do with the question asked and doesn't use any of the equivalent tables given in the question.